# Typeorm subquery raising an error syntax error at or near ")"

Tags: typescript, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I have three entities that are related first one being assessment, second one is grade, and the last one is user.

```js
@Entity()
export class Grade extends Audit {
    @ApiProperty()
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @ApiProperty()
    @Column({ nullable: false })
    grade: string;

    @ManyToOne(() => Assessment, (assessment: Assessment) => assessment.grade, {
        onDelete: 'RESTRICT',
    })
    assessment: Assessment;

    @ManyToOne(() => User, (candidate: User) => candidate.grade, {
        onDelete: 'RESTRICT',
    })
    candidate: User;
}
```

```js
@Entity()
export class Assessment extends Audit {
    @ApiProperty()
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @ApiProperty()
    @Column({ unique: true, nullable: false })
    title: string;

    @ApiProperty()
    @Column({ nullable: false })
    description: string;

    @ManyToOne(
        () => GradingPreference,
        (gradingType: GradingPreference) => gradingType.assessment,
        { onDelete: 'RESTRICT' },
    )
    gradingType: number;

    @OneToMany(() => Grade, (grade: Grade) => grade.assessment)
    grade: Grade[];

    @OneToMany(
        () => AssessmentRequest,
        (interested: AssessmentRequest) => interested.assessment,
    )
    interested: AssessmentRequest[];
}
```

```js
@Entity()
export class User extends Audit {
    @ApiProperty()
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @ApiProperty()
    @Column({ unique: true, nullable: false })
    email: string;

    @Column({ nullable: false })
    password?: string;

    @ApiProperty()
    @Column({ name: 'first_name' })
    firstName: string;

    @ApiProperty()
    @Column({ name: 'last_name' })
    lastName: string;
    
    @OneToMany(() => Grade, (grade: Grade) => grade.candidate)
    public grade: Grade[];
}
```

```js
async findAll(
        options: IPaginationOptions,
    ): Promise<Pagination<Assessment>> {
        const gradeQb = this.connection
            .getRepository(Grade)
            .createQueryBuilder('grade')
            .distinctOn(['grade.candidate']);

        const interestedQb = this.connection
            .getRepository(AssessmentRequest)
            .createQueryBuilder('assessmentRequest')
            .distinctOn(['assessmentRequest.candidate']);

        const query = await this.assessmentRepository
            .createQueryBuilder('assessment')
            .leftJoin('(' + gradeQb.getQuery() + ')', 'grade')
            .leftJoin('(' + interestedQb.getQuery() + ')', 'interested');

        return await paginate<Assessment>(query, options);
    }
```

The above service is supposed to return all the assessment with the user who have been graded but because it is possible to be graded more than 1 time I want all the returned grades to be retrieved with no duplicates.
**this is the typeorm logging results**

```js
query: SELECT COUNT(*) AS "value" FROM (SELECT "assessment"."isDeleted" AS "assessment_isDeleted", "assessment"."createdOn" AS "assessment_createdOn", "assessment"."lastUpdatedOn" AS "assessment_lastUpdatedOn", "assessment"."id" AS "assessment_id", "assessment"."title" AS "assessment_title", "assessment"."description" AS "assessment_description", "assessment"."gradingTypeId" AS "assessment_gradingTypeId" FROM "assessment" "assessment" LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT ON ("grade"."candidateId") "grade"."isDeleted" AS "grade_isDeleted", "grade"."createdOn" AS "grade_createdOn", "grade"."lastUpdatedOn" AS "grade_lastUpdatedOn", "grade"."id" AS "grade_id", "grade"."grade" AS "grade_grade", "grade"."assessmentId" AS "grade_assessmentId", "grade"."candidateId" AS "grade_candidateId" FROM "grade" "grade") "grade"  LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT ON ("assessmentRequest"."candidateId") "assessmentRequest"."isDeleted" AS "assessmentRequest_isDeleted", "assessmentRequest"."createdOn" AS "assessmentRequest_createdOn", "assessmentRequest"."lastUpdatedOn" AS "assessmentRequest_lastUpdatedOn", "assessmentRequest"."id" AS "assessmentRequest_id", "assessmentRequest"."assessmentId" AS "assessmentRequest_assessmentId", "assessmentRequest"."candidateId" AS "assessmentRequest_candidateId" FROM "assessment_request" "assessmentRequest") "interested") "uniqueTableAlias"
query failed: SELECT COUNT(*) AS "value" FROM (SELECT "assessment"."isDeleted" AS "assessment_isDeleted", "assessment"."createdOn" AS "assessment_createdOn", "assessment"."lastUpdatedOn" AS "assessment_lastUpdatedOn", "assessment"."id" AS "assessment_id", "assessment"."title" AS "assessment_title", "assessment"."description" AS "assessment_description", "assessment"."gradingTypeId" AS "assessment_gradingTypeId" FROM "assessment" "assessment" LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT ON ("grade"."candidateId") "grade"."isDeleted" AS "grade_isDeleted", "grade"."createdOn" AS "grade_createdOn", "grade"."lastUpdatedOn" AS "grade_lastUpdatedOn", "grade"."id" AS "grade_id", "grade"."grade" AS "grade_grade", "grade"."assessmentId" AS "grade_assessmentId", "grade"."candidateId" AS "grade_candidateId" FROM "grade" "grade") "grade"  LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT ON ("assessmentRequest"."candidateId") "assessmentRequest"."isDeleted" AS "assessmentRequest_isDeleted", "assessmentRequest"."createdOn" AS "assessmentRequest_createdOn", "assessmentRequest"."lastUpdatedOn" AS "assessmentRequest_lastUpdatedOn", "assessmentRequest"."id" AS "assessmentRequest_id", "assessmentRequest"."assessmentId" AS "assessmentRequest_assessmentId", "assessmentRequest"."candidateId" AS "assessmentRequest_candidateId" FROM "assessment_request" "assessmentRequest") "interested") "uniqueTableAlias"
error: error: syntax error at or near ")"
    at Parser.parseErrorMessage (/home/faisal/Documents/development/harambee/api/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:287:98)
    at Parser.handlePacket (/home/faisal/Documents/development/harambee/api/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:126:29)
    at Parser.parse (/home/faisal/Documents/development/harambee/api/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:39:38)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/faisal/Documents/development/harambee/api/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/index.js:11:42)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:526:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23) {
  length: 92,
  severity: 'ERROR',
  code: '42601',
  detail: undefined,
  hint: undefined,
  position: '1331',
  internalPosition: undefined,
  internalQuery: undefined,
  where: undefined,
  schema: undefined,
  table: undefined,
  column: undefined,
  dataType: undefined,
  constraint: undefined,
  file: 'scan.l',
  line: '1145',
  routine: 'scanner_yyerror'
}
query: SELECT "Schedule"."isDeleted" AS "Schedule_isDeleted", "Schedule"."createdOn" AS "Schedule_createdOn", "Schedule"."lastUpdatedOn" AS "Schedule_lastUpdatedOn", "Schedule"."id" AS "Schedule_id", "Schedule"."day" AS "Schedule_day", "Schedule"."start" AS "Schedule_start", "Schedule"."end" AS "Schedule_end", "Schedule"."maximumParticipant" AS "Schedule_maximumParticipant", "Schedule"."interestedCandidate" AS "Schedule_interestedCandidate", "Schedule"."expired" AS "Schedule_expired", "Schedule"."opportunityId" AS "Schedule_opportunityId" FROM "schedule" "Schedule"
```